# accessing data of bootstrap dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is a sample bootstrap dynamic table :
I want to access the data in the table

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mail
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mobile
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
                    1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
 </div>
  <p id="qoz">s</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
 $("#add_row").click(function(){
  $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

  $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
  i++; 
});
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
     if(i>1){
     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
     }
 });
});
```

how can I access the data in the table?

Comment: Please be specific you want to set the date to table or you want to get the value from table ??

Comment: Yes.. Please elaborate your question properly..

Comment: @ankitverma of course i want to set data to table and then use them somewhere else!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i want to set data and use them in my program. its a panel.

Comment: set data where? Your adding and delete functionality works well.. What else is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao look. i want to set some data to table and then insert them to an array and then do some calculations with it. but i dont know how to access the data in the query code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display data , kindly See bellow code (I've added show data button click )

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  
  $("#add_row").click(function(){
  var numTr = $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length;
  
  $('#tab_logic').append("<tr id='addr"+(numTr)+"'><td>"+ (numTr+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+numTr+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+numTr+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+numTr+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td></tr>");

});
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
     var notr = $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length
     if(notr>1){
        $("#addr"+(notr-1)).remove();
     }
 });
 
 
 $("#show_data").click(function(){
    var htmlString="";
    $("#tab_logic tbody tr").each(function(index,el){
       if(index<$("#tab_logic tbody tr").length) {
          var name = $("[name='name"+index+"']").val();
          var mail = $("[name='mail"+index+"']").val();
          var mobile = $("[name='mobile"+index+"']").val();
          console.log("Row "+index+" : [Name="+name+"] - [Mail="+mail +"] - [Mobile="+mobile+"]");
       htmlString += showDataHtml(index,name,mail,mobile)
       }
       $("#data-row").html(htmlString);
    });
 });
});

function showDataHtml(index,name,mail,mobile) {
  index++;
  return "<div class='col-md-12'>Row "+index+" : Name = "+name+" - Mail = "+mail+" - Mobile = "+mobile+"</div>"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mail
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mobile
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
                    1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
<a id='show_data' class=" btn btn-default">SHow Data</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="data-row" class="row clearfix">
    
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome , please see my updated answer , I've added rendring in html also , I managed to delete the row not only empty its content :)

Comment: If this helped you , please up and mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) ( like in this image => [image resolved](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you :)

Comment: sorry i found a bug in that code. when u add a row and then again delete it and again add a row the row number will be incorrect . in fact  it doesnt show the  deleted row but its not deleted. and when u click show data it returns undefined

Comment: HI @mjvoodoo I changed a little bit your code , to fix your issues :) now ithink it works fine :)

Comment: sorry but its not working . use to set variables to 3 row . then delete 2 row and again set variables to 3 row. when u click the get row data deleted variables are there . i think delete btn just deletes the actual row not its values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143425/discussion-between-brimos-and-mjvoodoo).

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
 $("#add_row").click(function(){
  $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

  $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
  i++; 
});
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
     if(i>1){
     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
     }
 });
  $('#Get_row_data').click(function(){
    $('[id^=addr]').each(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+id +' td input').each(function(){
          console.log($(this).val());
        });  
    });
 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mail
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Mobile
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
                    1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
<a id='Get_row_data' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Get Row Data</a>
```

Hello Please check this code This might help you out in solving your purpose.
What i did is i have added a new button to get the data from row.
I used **wildCard** Id of **Row** and fetch the value of input boxes.

Thanks

Comment: thank u very very much. but u know im not pro in web dev. could u do me a favor? change ur code and do smting that when i press the btn it shows the data under the table in the html page. thank u

Comment: @mjvoodoo but that will take some time. sure will help you out